# Show Disqus comments count in list articles

Tags: javascript, disqus

I have a list of articles in included: title of article, number of Disqus comments such as

```
(3) Article 1
(4) Article 2
(8) Article 3
```

Can it possible?
I've try following this article:

```
https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624-adding-comment-count-links-to-your-home-page
```

And add prefix `#disqus_thread` to each link of number of comment such as:

```
http://myproject.local/main/blog/3#disqus_thread
```

But I does not work.
How can I do that?

Comment: It is indeed possible. I have done this a number of times. Are you testing on localhost ?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing on localhost, using myproject.local domain.